# fetching database table file into one file in php

Tags: php

Hello iam trying to create a disciplinary system. i created a table where accused and the victim had to put their information. I have created another table for report and i have failed to combine all the information given in the first table into one doc file so that i can use it in report. I need help?

`enter code here`

```
    if(isset($_POST['call'])){
        $accused     = $_POST['dss'];
        $report= $_POST['cas'];
        $action = $_POST['uect'];
        $u_cat       = intval($_POST[id]);

        if($report ==''){
            echo "<font color='Green'><b>Please fill in the Report!</b></font>";
        }else{
            if($u_cat) $insert  = "update  discip_report set accused_student='$accused', case='$report', action_taken='$action' where id='$u_cat'";
            else $insert        = "insert into discip_report(accused_student, report, action_taken, date) values('$accused','$report', '$action', NOW())";
            $run                = mysql_query($insert);
            if ($run) {
                echo "<font color='Green'><b>The Category was added</b></font>";
            }else{
                echo "<font color='Green'><b>The Category was not added</b></font>";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: You should improve your Codeformat. And mysql_query() is already deprecated. You should also use mysqli_error() for debugging your Queries. Explain your Issue more.

Comment: thanks but how i fetch the info from the table into one file

Comment: If you mean a Textfile, you can use file_put_contents() to write Content into a File.

Comment: Thanks. Please can you fully explain by using a code coz am new to php and i didn't get what you said.

Comment: Here is everything you need to know: http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: thanks i have read through but it was too hard to use.

Comment: Then you need to learn the basics, because this one is super easy.